# Unexpected 'mysql_select_db' (T_STRING)?

Tags: php

okay guys, I've got a problem. I always get the following error line:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'mysql_select_db' (T_STRING) in line 10

here's the whole code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>test3</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$verbindung = mysql_connect("localhost, test3")
or die ("Fehler")

mysql_select_db("test3");
or die ("Verbindung nicht möglich..."); 

$datum = $_POST["datum"]; 
$autor = $_POST["autor"];
$newstext = $_POST["newstext"]; 

if($datum == "" or $autor == "" or $newstext == "") {
echo "FAIL"
} else {

$eintrag = "INSERT INTO test3
(datum, autor, newstext)

VALUES 
('$datum', '$autor', '$newstext')";

}

mysql_close($verbindung); 
?>
</body>                              
</html>
```

Comment: Always accept the useful answer which helps the poster to get more reputation.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33411437/mysql-connection-problems-getaddrinfo-failed-no-such-host-is-known for @Niranjan N Raju

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Totally u have **`missed 2 semicolons`** and **`added 1 extra semicolon`**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>test3</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$verbindung = mysql_connect("localhost, test3")
or die ("Fehler");    //----- semicolon here

mysql_select_db("test3")   //  remove semicolon here
or die ("Verbindung nicht möglich..."); 

$datum = $_POST["datum"]; 
$autor = $_POST["autor"];
$newstext = $_POST["newstext"]; 

if($datum == "" or $autor == "" or $newstext == "") {
echo "FAIL" ; //----- semicolon here
} else {

$eintrag = "INSERT INTO test3
(datum, autor, newstext)

VALUES 
('$datum', '$autor', '$newstext')";

}

mysql_close($verbindung); 
?>
</body>                              
</html>
```

Comment: Is it working fine??

Comment: the only problem i have, is that this line keeps showing up:  php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Der angegebene Host ist unbekannt. in

Comment: That line is not there in your code??

Comment: it's a error line, sorry I didn't said that.

Comment: ya but is that line present in your question??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93659/discussion-between-darkyagami-and-niranjan-n-raju).

Answer (score 1):

```
$verbindung = mysql_connect("localhost, test3")
or die ("Fehler"); << semicolon missing
```

You should add one here as well:

```
echo "FAIL"; << here
```

And you have one too much in another place:

```
mysql_select_db("test3"); << remove here
or die ("Verbindung nicht möglich...");
```

You will not get your programs to work without some accuracy.

Please also note that mysql extension is deprecated and will not be supported in PHP versions after PHP 5.5 (look at [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) extensions), and that your code is prone to [SQL Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Comment: Bittesehr... =) If it was useful to you, please consider accepting it.