# mysql_connection problems -- 'getaddrinfo failed', "No such host is known"?

Tags: php

I fixed my code after I asked the previous question, but now I get the in the title mentioned error line. Well here's to code, so you can figure out or at least help to undestand what the problem is:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>test3</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$verbindung = mysql_connect("localhost, vanille")
or die ("Fehler");

mysql_select_db("test3")
or die ("Verbindung nicht möglich..."); 

$datum = $_POST["datum"]; 
$autor = $_POST["autor"];
$newstext = $_POST["newstext"]; 

if($datum == "" or $autor == "" or $newstext == "") {
echo "FAIL";
} else {

$eintrag = "INSERT INTO test3
(datum, autor, newstext)

VALUES 
('$datum', '$autor', '$newstext')";

}

mysql_close($verbindung); 
?>
</body>                              
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just Replace Your code with given code

```
<html>
<head>
<title>test3</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$verbindung = mysql_connect("localhost","vanille")
or die ("Fehler");

mysql_select_db("test3")
or die ("Verbindung nicht möglich..."); 

$datum = $_POST["datum"]; 
$autor = $_POST["autor"];
$newstext = $_POST["newstext"]; 

if($datum == "" or $autor == "" or $newstext == "") {
echo "FAIL";
} else {

$eintrag = "INSERT INTO test3
(datum, autor, newstext)

VALUES 
('$datum', '$autor', '$newstext')";

}

mysql_close($verbindung); 
?>
</body>                              
</html>
```